# Is it possible to do if else before where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have variables and I want to check if the variables are not null or empty only then I want to initiate or include my where clause. The idea is as below. I checked but its showing syntax error.

```
    SELECT
        ID,
        BRANCHCODE,
        BRANCHNAME,
        DEPARTMENTCODE,
        DEPARTMENTNAME,
    FROM 
        dbo.RATINGLOGS

    IF (NULLIF(@BRANCHCODE, '') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        WHERE BRANCHCODE LIKE '%'@BRANCHCODE'%'
    END

    ORDER BY 
    RATINGTIMESTAMP OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply use a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE BRANCHCODE LIKE '%' + @BRANCHCODE + '%' OR
      NULLIF(@BRANCHCODE, '') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: wouldnt branchcode like '%null%' throw error? Because i only want to add the word 'where ... ' if condition is met or else continue with order by

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH . . . No.  It would evaluate to `NULL` and the other clause of the `OR` would be evaluated.

Comment: Thaks, but your answer only answers half of it. Like I mention, the where clause is only included if and only if the variables are not null. In other words if variables is null, show all results. Now if variable is null it doesnt show any resultsHow to do that.

Comment: It will work exactly like you want. (ISNULL(@BRANCHCODE,'')='' will be true, so OR will be true and all records will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
        ID,
        BRANCHCODE,
        BRANCHNAME,
        DEPARTMENTCODE,
        DEPARTMENTNAME,
    FROM 
        dbo.RATINGLOGS   

        WHERE (ISNULL(@BRANCHCODE,'')='' OR  BRANCHCODE LIKE '%'@BRANCHCODE'%')


    ORDER BY 
    RATINGTIMESTAMP OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```